# What is best approach to detect outliers?

Tags: algorithm, data-science, normal-distribution, outliers

I have a stream of numbers coming in and I want to flag them as 1 if outlier and 0 if not an outlier. I have two approaches for it:

1) I calculate rolling mean of numbers coming in. Then, I calculate the rolling standard deviation of the calculated mean of numbers. With these values, I create confidence bound with (μ ± 3σ) 
2) I calculate rolling mean and standard deviation of numbers coming in.  With these values, I create confidence bound with (μ ± 3σ)

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on your application.

That being said, the second approach looks like a standard (some would call it naive) solution. The the first approach seems very strange and just off:

Imagine only two alternating numbers coming in. Let's say 0 and 10. After a while you will have a very stable mean of 5 +- ε (with ε converging 0). Thus the standard deviation of these means will get smaller and smaller as you progress. Eventually, 3σ will be smaller than 5 and all incoming numbers from then on will be outliers.